# What’s the significance of the number “536870916” in computer science

Tags: math, binary, numbers, computer-science

I’ve noticed in many games there are a lot of errors regarding the number 536870916. For example, in one game that’s coded in Lua, the maximum number you can damage an enemy is 536870916, which is undocumented. I noticed other errors regarding this number when I googled it, for example:

1. “Random crash "Failed to allocate 536870916 bytes and will now terminate"”

Does anyone happen to know why this is?

Comment: It's almost certainly that it's "one tick" above a power of two, meaning that certain kinds of off-by-one errors would trigger it. Any chance that in the game, the maximum possible HP is 536870912?

Comment: @javedb take a look at this: https://unknownworlds.com/ns2/32bit/

Comment: It is `0x20000004`, which you could have easily discovered for yourself, which has no significance whatsoever in computer science.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing all that special about 536870916. It just happens to be very close to a power of 2: 2<sup>29</sup> = 536870912.

536870912 bytes is 512MiB, or 0.5GiB. It's a reasonable memory limit to configure for an application, so numbers going slightly above it are bound to appear in crash reports.

If you search numbers 536870912-536870916 on Google you'll see a diminishing number of results:

- 536870912: 47,500,000 results
- 536870913: 7,920,000 results
- 536870914: 36,300 results
- 536870915: 7,720 results
- 536870916: 8,380 results

Another source where you might see 536870916 is when numbers are used as  bit sets to store flags. Sometimes error codes are stored like this. In binary, 536870916 has only 2 bits set, which makes it a union of two flags.